# PassportJS Session doesn't working with custom callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

The below custom call back for passport.js doesn't seems to work, no mater what i do.

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, users, info) {
    console.log(users);
    if (user === false) {
      console.log('Failed!');
    } else {
      res.redirect('/');
    }
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

The same if i change it to like below all works as expected.

```
app.post("/login" 
    ,passport.authenticate('local',{
        successRedirect : "/",
        failureRedirect : "/login",
    })
);
```

Also I've noticed when using custom callback even the `passport.serializeUser` and `passport.deserializeUser` also not getting invoked by passport.js.

Is this any sort of a bug or am i doing something wrong here ??

**My Local-Strategy:**

```
    passport.use('local-sigin',new LocalStrategy({
    // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
    usernameField : 'email',
    passwordField : 'password',
    passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
},
function(req, email, password, done) { // callback with email and password from our form
    console.log('Passport Strategy Sign in:');
    // find a user whose email is the same as the forms email
    // we are checking to see if the user trying to login already exists
    User.findOne({ 'email' : email }, function(err, user) {
        // if there are any errors, return the error before anything else
        if (err)
            return done({status:'ERROR',message:'Something went wrong!'});

        // if no user is found, return the message
        if (!user)
            return done({status:'ERROR',message:'No user found.'}, false);

        // if the user is found but the password is wrong
        if (!user.validPassword(password))
            return done({status:'ERROR',message:'Oops! Wrong password.'}, false);

        // all is well, return successful user
        return done({status:'OK',message:'Login success.'}, user);
    });
}));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am guessing that by 'doesn't work' you mean to say that the user is never being logged in.

Firstly, your local strategy is named 'local-sigin' however on a POST to '/login' you are invoking the 'local' strategy, which presumably doesn't exist:

```
passport.use('local', new LocalStrategy({
```

Change the name of your strategy to be consistent (or vice versa!):

```
passport.authenticate('local'
```

Secondly, your 'local' authentication callback has a parameter `users` (plural) but you are trying to access `user` (singular) within its body, meaning `user` is undefined and `user === false` is false under strict equality:

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
                                            // ^^^^
    console.log(user);
    if (!user) {
      console.log('Failed!');
    } else {
      res.redirect('/');
    }
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

And finally, you are never logging the user in when authentication is successful. Creating a session for a user is not automatic, you must call [`req#login`](http://passportjs.org/docs/login):

> Passport exposes a `login()` function on `req` (also aliased as `logIn()`) that can be used to establish a login session.

Let's add that to your authentication callback:

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    console.log(user);
    if (!user) {
      console.log('Failed!');
    } else {
      req.login(user, function (err) {
          if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
          }
          res.redirect('/');
      });
    }
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

Take a look at the [Passport docs](http://passportjs.org/docs), they explain in a good amount of detail how these processes work and how to implement them.

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution ;)